# Bipartite Undirected Graph Test: Converting to check nodes with strings instead of integers

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, graph, bipartite

I'm working on a bipartite test for undirected graphs, using adjacency-list representation. The user inputs the nodes and what they connect to, with each line being a pair. For example:

```
0 1 
2 3
1 2
0 3
```

means 0 is connected to 1 and 3, 2 is connected to 1 and 3, etc. The algorithm does a BFS, coloring nodes as it goes, and seeing if it can be bipartite. In addition to seeing if the graph is bipartite, it stores and outputs which nodes belong to which group in sorted order. Following the previous example, 1 and 3 would be in group A, 2 and 0 would be group B. The sample output would be:

```
Group A:
0
2
Group B:
1
3
```

As best I can tell, the current algorithm works fine, has little to no problem, save a few "messy" code bits here and there that could be cleaned up. Here's the entire program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<map>
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
#include<set>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int>vec[50];
map<int,int>color;
queue<int>q;

vector<int> B;
vector<int> H;

bool check(int n, int src){
    q.push(src);
    int i;
    color[src]=1;
    while(!q.empty()){
        src = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for(i=0;i<vec[src].size();i++){
            if(color[vec[src][i]]==-1){ //vec[src][i] = data; color[src] = color;
                color[vec[src][i]]= 1 - color[src];
                q.push(vec[src][i]);
                if (color[src] == 0 
                  and find(B.begin(), B.end(), vec[src][i]) == B.end()
                  and find(H.begin(), H.end(), vec[src][i]) == H.end()){
                    B.push_back(vec[src][i]);   }
                else if (color[src] == 1 
                   and find(B.begin(), B.end(), vec[src][i]) == B.end() 
                   and find(H.begin(), H.end(), vec[src][i]) == H.end()){
                    H.push_back(vec[src][i]);   }
            }
            else if(color[vec[src][i]]== color[src]){
                return 0;   }
            else{
                if(find(B.begin(), B.end(), vec[src][i]) != B.end()){
                    break;  }
                else if(find(H.begin(), H.end(), vec[src][i]) != H.end()){
                    break;  }
                else{ B.push_back(vec[src][i]); }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int distinct(const vector<int>& v){
    set<int> distinct_container;
    for(auto curr_int = v.begin(), end = v.end(); curr_int != end; ++curr_int){
    distinct_container.insert(*curr_int);  }
return distinct_container.size();
}

int main() {
    int inp; int index = 0; vector<int> Input;
    while (cin >> inp){
        Input.push_back(inp);   }
    int points = distinct(Input); 
    while(index < points){
        color[index]= - 1; index++;  }
    index = 0; 
    while(index < Input.size()){
        vec[Input[index]].push_back(Input[index + 1]);
        vec[Input[index + 1]].push_back(Input[index]);
        index += 2;
    }
    bool res = 1; index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < points; i++){
        if(color[i]==-1){
            res = res && check(points, i); }
    } 
    if(res){ 
        sort(B.begin(), B.end());
        sort(H.begin(), H.end()); 
        cout << "Group A:\n"; int x = 0;
        while (x < B.size()){
            cout << B[x] << "\n"; x++;  }
        cout << "Group B:\n"; int y = 0;
        while (y < H.size()){
            cout << H[y] << "\n"; y++;  }
    }
    else{
        cout << "IMPOSSIBLE";   } 
    return 0;
    }
```

Now, the problem I'm having is I have to convert the nodes to have a string as data, rather than an integer. Instead of pairing numbers like 1 and 2, I want to pair names like Jane and Frank, following the same input syntax as previous example: single white space between them indicates pairing. Still testing the nodes if they're bipartisan, coloring them in the search, adding them to vectors to output later in their respective groups. All that is changing is the data type of the input. And I've made no progress in my attempts.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated. I'm mostly looking for the fix on the data types, but I'll take criticism and recommendations on any of it. Please give me something more to work with. Thank you in advance.

Edit: following the idea laid out to me by kraskevich, I think I have it somewhat going. But I've run into two new problems: getting the maps back together at the end to output the names, and the current algorithm, not matter the input, returns IMPOSSIBLE.

New code: only main changed, and extra global declarations of more vectors.

```
map<string, int> toNum;
vector<string> numToString;
vector<int> BN;
vector<int> HN;
vector<string> BS;
vector<string> HS; 
................
int main(){
    string s; vector<int> Input; int edges = 0;
    while (cin >> s){
    edges++;    }
    int id; int index = 0; int points = 0;
    if (toNum.find(s) != toNum.end()){
        id = toNum[s];  }
    else{
        numToString.push_back(s);
        toNum.insert( pair<int, string>(numToString.size() - 1, s));
        id = numToString.size() - 1; ++points;
        Input.push_back(id);    }
    while(index < points){
        color[index]= - 1; index++;  }
    index = 0;
    while(index < numToString.size()){
        vec[Input[index]].push_back(Input[index + 1]);
        vec[Input[index + 1]].push_back(Input[index]);
        index += 2;
    }
    bool res = 1; index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < points; i++){
        if(color[i]==-1){
            res = res && check(points, i); }
    }
    if(res){
        index = 0; int key = 0; string name;
        while (index < BN.size()){
            name = toNum[BN[index]];
            BS.push_back(name);
            index++;    }
        index = 0;
        while (index < HN.size()){
            name = toNum[BN[index]];
            HS.push_back(name);
            index++;    }
        sort(BS.begin(), BS.end());
        sort(HS.begin(), HS.end());
        cout << "GROUP A\n"; int x = 0;
        while (x < BS.size()){
             cout << BS[x] << "\n"; x++;  }
        cout << "GROUP B\n"; int y = 0;
        while (y < HS.size()){
            cout << HS[y] << "\n"; y++;  }
    }
    else{
        cout << "IMPOSSIBLE";   }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not change the implementation of the breadth first search. Instead, you can simply map all strings to numbers, run the existing implementation and them map numbers back to strings.

How to preform the mapping? Something like that:

```
// A mapping from strings to their ids.
std::map<std::string, int> toNum;
// A mapping from ids to strings.
std::vector<std::string> numToString;
...
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
int id;
if (toNum.find(s) != toNum.end()) {
    id = toNum[s];
} else {
    numToString.push_back(s);
    id = numToString.size() - 1;
    toNum[s] = id;
}
```